# Update/Requery textbox after cascading combo box

Tags: ms-access, combobox, textbox, vba, cascadingdropdown

I have a form with two dependent cascading combo boxes with a textbox. What I want it to do is after I select the 2nd combo boxes (cboxHDD), the txtDescription would update or requery to the selection of cboxHDD. I found some examples online but I can't seem to get it to work update/requery.

The code to txtDescription:

```html
    With Me
        .txtDescription.Value = cboxHDD.Column(3)
    End With
```

The database is also provided in the following link:
[Computer-HDD Database](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=558CDD62356141AF!6921&authkey=!AHjUdTCYI4zpbRE&ithint=file%2Caccdb)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting `txtDescription.Value = cboxHDD.Column(3)` in the "After Update" event of cboxHDD?

Comment: I just tried putting that in, and the results is that when I select the 2nd combo box, txtDescription just goes blank.

Comment: Are you sure there is something present in .Column(3). Set a breakpoint and look at cboxHDD to see what is available in each Column.

Comment: I even set it to .Column(2) to check, and there is data in both 1st, 2nd, and 3rd columns of the query but it still goes blank.

Comment: Check the properties of the Textbox.  Maybe it is bound to some other source.

Comment: OK. I downloaded the database.  I got it to work using `cboxHDD.Column(0)`

Comment: Thanks! I tried it and it work but it is showing me values from the HDD columns of the query and not the description. Maybe I must have done something wrong with the query.

Comment: I'm thinking your version of the database no longer matches what is in the Computer-HDD Database link. Does the first combo box show you what it is supposed to?

Comment: Yeah the first combo box and the second one is showing what it needs to. I'm going to busy this week but I'll try to figure it out next week and will let you know.